# android: extending CheckedTextView source code

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I was thinking of adding an icon to the items in a ListView who already has a text and a checkbox: simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml which is nothing but a < CheckedTextView > tag with some attributes

I'm aware of the custom adapter solution, but I really want and more intuitive solution.
I know playing with the source code is not intuitive, but what I meant is the easiness of just doing this:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, // context
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,  // view for an item in the list
                myCursor,                                           // cursor used for populating list items
                new String[] {dBHelper.CONTACT_NAME},               // column in cursor we are getting data from
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1});                    // where to put this data in the item's view
```

and the results can be taken with something like this:

```
SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
```

with whatever code written in separate files

---

**Using the source code from:** http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.3_r1/android/widget/CheckedTextView.java/

**My problem is** that eclipse cannot resolve:  *R.styleable.CheckedTextView* and *mPaddingRight*
in:

```
TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.CheckedTextView, defStyle, 0);
```

and

```
Drawable d = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CheckedTextView_checkMark);
```

and

```
boolean checked = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CheckedTextView_checked, false);
```

**AND**

```
mPaddingRight = mCheckMarkWidth + mBasePaddingRight;
            d.setState(getDrawableState());
        } else {
            mPaddingRight = mBasePaddingRight;
        }
```

and

```
@Override
    public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
        mBasePaddingRight = mPaddingRight;
    }
```

Thank you... :)

Comment: You need to switch `R.xxxx` to `android.R.xxxx` and the other attributes are hidden inside Android code. If they don't show up, it's because they're private APIs

Comment: All you have to do is provide your own layout instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`, no need to muck around in source code. Or, if you need to add functionality to CheckedTextView, subclass it and add what you need (Note: You'd still need to provide a new layout file to use this subclass).

Comment: #nEx.Software I forgot to say that android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice xml file is nothing but a <CheckedTextView> tag [I've edited my question too]. Thus, in order to provide the xml file I want I need to extend the CheckedTextView... or at least understand it

Comment: #Joe Simpson
I've tried that and it didn't work. Apparently It doesn't work on styleables

Comment: @himura I know that it's just a CheckedTextView. But the fact remains that all you need to do is use a different layout if all you want to do is add an icon. I'll post as an answer though, since comments aren't the right place.

Comment: OK i'm waiting for your answer, and i'm trying your advice too. Another question emerges. If i want to be able to click on the icon as well, and then i go to another activity or do something without checking the box. Is that possible? If still researching and should not ask about it before doing my homework, but just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you don't need to go to source if all you want to do is add an icon to the ListView items. Just create a new layout that described what you want. I've included an example below, but that's just one way of doing it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon1"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

then, in your Activity code do something like:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
// I'm just going to use an ArraySdapter, for simplicity...

listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, android.R.id.text1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items)));

// or, for the sake of example (note, not optimized at all)

listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, android.R.id.text1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items)) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
        return view;
    }
});
```

Note, the above gives more flexibility, but you could also have just added an android:drawableLeft attribute to the CheckedTextView instead of adding the RelativeLayout and ImageView.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful... one thing though, when i'm clicking on an item, nothing happens, it doesn't get clicked... I'm still trying to get this working... I've added         lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); and lv..setClickable(false); lv.setItemsCanFocus(false); [I've tried the 4 possible combinations of the last two sets]

Comment: Ah, yeah, since your relative layout does not implement Checkable, it doesn't get checked. The way I've handled this in the past is to make a subclass of RelativeLayout called CheckedRelativeLayout which passes down the checked state to the CheckedTextView. It's a little more complicated but it works ok.

Comment: Is there a layout that is already clickable or I'll have to override some layout anyways?

Comment: I'm not aware of any particular layout that implements Checkable, unfortunately.

Comment: @himura: I went ahead and made a basic implementation which you can download at: http://www.nexsoftware.net/uploads/CheckedRelativeLayout.zip

Comment: Oh that is nice of you, I was just about to create one. Thank you

Comment: I'm trying to add a button to the list item, that works, but if i click elsewhere in the item, it doesn't get checked. I don't want a solution for that, but its clear that I'm missing some concepts regarding views and click events [just like i didn't know that i need the RelativeLayout to be clickable]... do you know any good reference where I can learn the core of those topics? is there a book or something?