# ListItem click and checkbox click at the same time

Tags: android, listview

I've been trying many things with list items and i'm facing some problems. In [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712978/android-extending-checkedtextview-source-code), thanks to @nEx.Software i was able to resolve the problem. But I'm still missing some concepts here.

Right now i'm trying to differentiate between an item's click and a checkbox within it. However, I want to do it without extending the array adapter. Is there a way to use both methods: listView.onItemClickListener() AND listView.getCheckedItemPositions(), together!

There should be a way to use an xml file [doesn't matter how complex it gets] along with extending the available Views and this thing should be done.

Putting it simple, open the gmail app, and u'll find all emails listed with checkboxes where u can click on the checkbox to mark it OR the rest of the item to open the email.
Again, I know that it is doable with extending Adapters and adding an Array for the checkboxes, but, is it possible to use the convenient methods: listView.onItemClickListener() AND listView.getCheckedItemPositions()? is CheckedTextView a part of the solution?

One more thing, rather than just answering me [where i become lazy]
Wheather it is possible or not, is there a verry reliable reference for such issues? I would really like to fully understand everything that goes into this matter... if its not possible, i must be able to tell why!

Thank you :)

Comment: I've tried to use a CheckedTextView and a Button together,,, the button works, but the CheckedTextView doesn't get clickable as soon as i add the button, it seems that if there's a clickable view inside the item, the item is not clickable anymore, and the CheckedTextView relays on the item click rather than clicking it somehow... those are the conclusions that I got to, not sure if any of them is actually correct... the RelativeLayout was extended to be checkable as done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712978/android-extending-checkedtextview-source-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add custom row into your listview. into your custom row you add one textview and checkbox into linerlayout and get linerlayout click event.

Comment: But still, with this, how can I see which items are checked? and I wanted a checkbox with a button, not a text,,, anywaysm its the same thing